# Creating a new api route and file fails, but appending to an existing route works

Tags: node.js

I am trying to request data from my node server (via a React client), but it doesn't want to work, despite it working for previous routes in the same manner.

I added a new route (`'/api/posts'`) that I call from a React app:

```
getPosts().then(result => { ...
```

```
export const getPosts = () => {
  return getData('/api/posts');
}
```

```
const getData = (path) => {
  return axios.get(path);
}
```

Up to here there is no problem. But when the axios fetch call is sent, my node console goes bonkers, outputting a crazy amount of text, it seems in a loop:

[image]

Here you can see what happens in action in this streamed video:

https://streamable.com/tnext

I don't understand why this is happening.

I have other routes, that all work fine. All I did was create a new route (`'/api/posts'`) and file, and tried to get a console output once it's reached:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import groups from './groups';
import recentActivity from './recentActivity';
import auth from './auth/auth';
import manage from './manage/manage';
import posts from './posts';

//Routes to use for /api/ root path
const router = new Router();
router.use('/groups', groups);
router.use('/recentactivity', recentActivity);
router.use('/auth', auth);
router.use('/manage', manage);
router.use('/posts', posts);

export default router;
```

```
import { Router } from 'express';

const router = new Router();

router.get('/posts', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('server posts request')
  res.json({posts: 'posts'});
})

export default router;
```

Can you tell me why node is freaking out and outputting all that text. Maybe it's all the `request` data, but why is it doing this? And how do I fix it? I simply don't understand why this is happening...

If I put the route in an existing route, like `/api/recentActivity/posts`, it works. But when I try to have it as it's own route, it does the crazy console output. I don't understand why this is happening.

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't the resultant url be `/api/posts/posts`?

Comment: Oh crap, what a stupid mistake! Thank you for pointing out the obvious to me :P Please submit an answer and I will vote it up. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the url you should be requesting should be `/api/posts/posts`. Because `router.use('/posts', posts)` and  `router.get('/posts'` both add `/posts` in url..